# Which one is the closest meaning to the "secured" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

Here is a question.

> We have **secured** discounted rates for conference participants at Hotel Cortiana.

The word "secured" is closest in meaning to
(A)guarded
(B)established
(C)paid
(D)enclosed

I think it's closest in meaning to "guaranteed", so I'm confused about these options which not properly fit the sentence for me. 
The correct is B, I really want to know why. I have known and looked up that "establish" is closest to "found", "build" and "accept". The meaning in verb of "secure" is very different from "establish". 
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary defintion of secure that is being used here is:

> To put beyond hazard of not receiving; to make certain;

The meaning is close to guaranteed.  The only word from the list that is close is establish, which has a dictionary defintion:

> To make stable or firm

I hope you can see the connection between "to make certain" and "to make firm"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have found the meaning you said isn't in the dictionary which I love to use online. Could you tell me what the dictionary you are using?  Is it online?

Comment: this was wiktionary.  (should have linked)